# How to insert column value from a stored procedure result in to a vaiable

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure will return a result set with a few columns.
Now i want the value of one of the columns(from the result set) into one variable.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @T Table(Column)
Declare  @Column int

INSERT INTO @T(COLUMN)
EXEC yourStoredprocedure

Select @Column = YourColumn From @T
```

Comment: my stored proc returns around 40 columns result set.But i just need only few columns values from them.So creating a Table with 40 columns is unnecessary i feel.

Comment: You must define your table with 40 column. SQL Server don't have a way to select only specify column from stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
-- Your procedure
SELECT @myVariable=myColum FROM myTable
```